# ResponseJson in wso2esb 4.9.0 is getting in tags format

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I’m working with wso2esb 4.9.0 and Wso2dss3.0.0

i have a simple select service as shown below.

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="Simpleselect"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="messagetype"
                   value="application/json"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="usercode"
                   expression="//usercode/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:username_op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <p:usercode>$1</p:usercode>
               </p:username_op>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('usercode')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send receive="simpletest">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/muser_DataService/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Sequence:

```
<sequence name="simpletest" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
    <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" value="POST"/>
    <property expression="//s:Datalist" name="Datalist" scope="default"
        type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
        xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
    <property expression="count(//s:Datalist)" name="Total"
        scope="default" type="STRING"
        xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
        xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:s="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"/>
    <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
        xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xpath="get-property('Total')='0.0'">
        <then>
            <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                        <Body>
                            <Datalist>Not Found</Datalist>
                        </Body>
                        <Status>404</Status>
                    </ResponseJSON>
                </format>
            </payloadFactory>
            <send/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property action="remove" name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                        <Body>$1</Body>
                        <Status>200</Status>
                        <Total>$2</Total>
                    </ResponseJSON>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Datalist')"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Total')"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <send/>
        </else>
    </filter>
</sequence>
```

When i call this services using CURL its gives me a response in form of tags as shown

```
<ResponseJSON><Body><Datalist xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><userid>-1899999899</userid><username>Vikash Sinha</username><usercode>vikash</usercode></Datalist></Body><Status>200</Status><Total>1.0</Total></ResponseJSON>
```

Am expecting the result in form of {} like

```
{"ResponseJSON":{"Body":{"Datalist":parameters},"Status":"200","Total":"1.0"}}
```

message formatter and builders in axix2.xml are

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>
<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
```

logs:

```
[2015-09-15 10:44:02,979]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:942e2525-29f7-4ef6-b64f-709ea41f4bbf, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><DataCollection xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><Datalist><partybranchid>2127629166052452</partybranchid><partybranchname>other locations</partybranchname><partyid>460077453499443</partyid><partyname>Youtility Technologies Pvt Ltd</partyname><ouid>-1</ouid><organizationunitname>NONE</organizationunitname><inchargeid>-1899999899</inchargeid><sbuheadid>-1</sbuheadid><usercriteriaconfigid>1187416899913503</usercriteriaconfigid><primarymail>vikash@myunisoft.com</primarymail></Datalist><Datalist><partybranchid>2545910581364239</partybranchid><partybranchname>DBPB001</partybranchname><partyid>2534954639984412</partyid><partyname>DBPRTY001</partyname><ouid>2538210579514587</ouid><organizationunitname>DBORG001</organizationunitname><inchargeid>2540093122446574</inchargeid><sbuheadid>1209449655666077</sbuheadid><usercriteriaconfigid>1187416899913503</usercriteriaconfigid><primarymail>vikash@myunisoft.com</primarymail></Datalist></DataCollection></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: First of all put log mediator in receive sequence and check log that response actually processed by out sequence. Second of all open browser developer console and check what is then value of Content-Type header for request

Comment: Another case is "messagetype" in example u provide is different with "messageType" in documentation. Java lang case sensitive

Comment: I have put log mediatro and done some changes as u said but am getting the same response in tag format i think this is the cause messagebuilder  in asis2.xml its not converting the soap message to JSONresponse  in the payload mediator,U have any idea..

Comment: I´ve checked the source code for the PayloadMediator and it seems to set the messageType property based on the supplied media-type. Did you try to move the <property name="messageType" > mediator to just before you send the reply message ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. I am sending an XML input to my proxy which is interecting with some target system and receiving XML response and providing response in JSON format to the client.

**Proxy Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="StackOverflow_Proxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="usercode"
                   expression="//usercode/text()"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                                 xmlns:dat="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                  <soapenv:Header/>
                  <soapenv:Body>
                     <dat:getChainInfo>
                        <dat:usercode>$1</dat:usercode>
                     </dat:getChainInfo>
                  </soapenv:Body>
               </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('usercode')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <header name="Action" scope="default" value="urn:getChainInfo"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="============= REQUEST ============" expression="$body"/>
         </log>
         <send receive="simpleTest">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8001/services/DataService_Proxy"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

**SimpleTest Sequence:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="simpleTest" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
    <log>
        <property expression="$body"
            name="============ RESPONSE =================" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
    <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" value="POST"/>
    <property name="RESPONSE" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property
        expression="$body/*[local-name() = 'ChainDesc']"
        name="responseDocument" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{
  "ResponseJSON": {
    "Body": "$1",
    "Status": "200",
    "Total": "1.0"
  }
}</format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml"
                expression="get-property('responseDocument')" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <send/>
</sequence>
```

**axis2.xml** configuration is as below.

```
<messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>

<messageFormatter contentType="application/json/badgerfish"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBadgerfishMessageFormatter"/>

<messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>

<messageBuilder contentType="application/json/badgerfish"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONBadgerfishOMBuilder"/>
```

**Response** Recieved

```
    {
  "ResponseJSON": {
    "Body": "{"ChainDesc":{"O_text":4,"O_status":6,"O_msg":"SuccessFul"}}",
    "Status": "200",
    "Total": "1.0"
  }
}
```

Hope it will help. Thanks!!

Comment: Am working in wso2esb 4.9.0 version,I have tried this  it is also returning me in tag format.

Comment: It was on wso2esb 4.8.1 and working fine.Just downloaded wso2esb 4.9.0 and facing the same problem. I think we have workaround here. Just take media-type as 'json' and put json body in payload factory. I am passing an XML as argument as you were doing and ESB is converting that XML to JSON and giving response in desired format. I have updated my answer as well.

Comment: yeah actually i have tried this media-type as 'JSON' and the response was what i was expecting,But actually am trying to do this with the media-type xml its working in all previous versions but not in 4.9.0 don't no why.

Answer (score 0):

[From WSO2 documentation:](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/PayloadFactory+Mediator)

"If you want to change the payload type of the outgoing message, such as to change it to JSON, add the messageType property after the `</payloadFactory>`"

```
...
</payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
```

[image]

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using  `<payloadFactory media-type="xml">` so it will return the output in XML format only.  if you want it in json then change the payload factory to,

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
    <format>{
  "ResponseJSON": {
"Body": "$1",
"Status": "200",
"Total": "$2"
 }
}</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Datalist')"/>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('Total')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
<send/>
```

Hope this helps !!